# EF Core 1.0: How to query a whole tree?

Tags: c#, linq, tree, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF 7.0.0.0-rc1-final.

I have a tree structure with one-to-many relationships from GrandGrandParent to GrandParent to Parent to Child:

```
public class GrandGrandParent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<GrandParent> GrandParents { get; set; }

    public GrandGrandParent()
    {
        this.GrandParents = new List<GrandParent>();
    }
}

public class GrandParent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual GrandGrandParent GrandGrandParent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

    public GrandParent()
    {
        this.Parents = new List<Parent>();
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual GrandParent GrandParent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {
        this.Children = new List<Child>();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF Core 1.0 (EF 7), how can I create a LINQ query (or with sub-queries) that give me the whole tree, given a certain grand-grand-parent ID?

I can .Include() one level up or down, maybe I'm blind for the obvious? This gives me the GrandGrandParent and the list of GrandParents:

```
var ggparent1 = from ggp in myDbContext.GrandGrandParent
                .Include(ggp => ggp.GrandParents)
                where ggp.ID == 2
                select ggp;
```

I want to get the whole tree, down to the list of children. Must I resort to code a foreach() loop and manually build the tree?

Comment: How is designed your database ? You have 4 tables, 2 or 1 ? Despite the fact that your hierarchy is strange, having the number of tables could guide us to help you (especially with includes and joins)

Comment: There are 4 tables, one for each class. The hierarchy is chosen to show my problem in a generic way, so readers won't have to bother to learn the business logic too. I have tried variations on the following LINQ:

var gparents = from gp in myDbContext.GrandParent
                .Include(gparent => gparent.GrandGrandParent)
                .Include(gparent => gparent.Parents)
                .ThenInclude(children => children.Select(child => child.ID))
                where gp.GrandGrandParent.ID == 2
                select gp;
but .ThenInclude always throws an exception.

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: The properties expression 'children => {from Parent child in children select [child].ID}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

Comment: My test application: [http://pastebin.com/b2tWS7LC](http://pastebin.com/b2tWS7LC) and the EF classes as above.

Comment: I respect your table design but if you really have a hierarchy structure, why not to merge them all in one table and have unlimited level of hierarchy. I successfully implemented it via sql `HierarchyID` in EF6 with unlimited levela. Having 1 table makes most of your queries super simple. Each row should have a `ParentID` referring to a row ID in the table with the root nodes having that as `null`.

Comment: @MohsenAfshin they are different business objects with very different information, so that's not an option. And the problem is with the List<> of children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just go with the Linq form:

```
private static void Test0(ApplicationDbContext myDbContext)
{
    var ggparent = myDbContext.GrandGrandParents
        .Include(ggp => ggp.GrandParents)
        .ThenInclude(gp => gp.Parents)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Children)
        .FirstOrDefault(ggp => ggp.ID == 3);

    if (ggparent == null)
    {
        DebugPrint("GrandGrandParent not found");
        return;
    }

    DebugPrint("GrandGrandParent:");
    DebugPrint(ggparent);


    if (ggparent.GrandParents == null)
    {
        DebugPrint("GrandParents null");
        return;
    }

    foreach (var gparent in ggparent.GrandParents)
    {
        DebugPrint(gparent);
        if (gparent.Parents == null) continue;
        foreach (var parent in gparent.Parents)
        {
            DebugPrint(parent);
            if (parent.Children == null) continue;
            foreach (var child in parent.Children)
            {
                DebugPrint(child);
            }
        }
    }

    int changeCount = myDbContext.SaveChanges();
    DebugPrint(string.Format("ChangeCount={0}", changeCount));
}
```

Then you do not have to do the sub queries by your own. But you can add logging to see the SQL queries EF actually creates.

If you need the complete tree you do not need `select`. You can use select to extract a part of the result tree or to build a new (flat) object out of the hierarchy.

An example where I flatten a hierarchy with only two levels (with many-to-many) to get the Items for a grouped SelectList:

```
var result =
    (from c in dbContext.EventTypes
    join j in dbContext.EventType2EventTypes on c.Id equals j.ChildEventTypeId
    join p in dbContext.EventTypes on j.ParentEventTypeId equals p.Id
    where p.EventTypeLevel == EventTypeLevel.First && c.EventTypeLevel == EventTypeLevel.Second
    orderby p.SortOrder, p.Id, c.SortOrder, c.Id
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = c.NameDe,
        Value = c.Id.ToString(),
        Group = GetParentEventTypeSelectListGroup(p.NameDe)
    }).AsNoTracking();
```